# On button event send an mail in html

Tags: html

I'm using the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <form method="post" action="mailto:hr@kine.com" >
        <input type="submit" value="Send Email" /> 
    </form>
</div>
```

However, when I try and load the page, I get the following error:

> No webpage was found for the web address

Why does this happen, and how can I fix this?

Comment: what url are you visiting to get to this code and what file are you saving this in on your file server?

Comment: `action` means the page where you'll jump for process the code. In action write the file name!!!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What language are you using for server side processing???

Comment: My first thought was the same as the other commenters, but it turns out `mailto` is a valid action. http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/interact/forms.html  What browser are you using. I will say that mailto in a form is not a common occurance.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to send email using php & html

```
<div>
        <form method="post">
                  <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Send Email" /> 
        </form>
</div>

    <?php

    if(isset($POST['submit']){
        $to = 'hr@kine.com';

        $subject = 'Website Change Reqest';

        $headers = "From: test@example.com\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: test@example.com\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


        $message = 'Test Email';
        $message .= '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>';


        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    }
?>
```

I hope it can help you.